# Is There any Way to Open Another Fragment From OnClick on Recycler View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter, android-fragmentactivity

When I Click On Photo To execute On Click Event of Recycler View  to Open Another Fragment I get This Error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

```
holder.pics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Open Another Fragment
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", String.valueOf(jName));

        Kitdetail_Fragment jerseyFragment = new Kitdetail_Fragment();
        jerseyFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelay, jerseyFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create interface in adapter class.
2. Call interface from your main activity/fragment.
3. From your fragment or activity class, navigate to your desire class.

By the way error show in this line.

> bundle.putString("name", String.valueOf(jName));

Check value of jName.